# ElasticSearch regexp failed with dot character in terms

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

Here is my settings and mapping:

```
{
  'settings': {
    'index':{
       'analysis':{
          'analyzer':{
             'analyzer_keyword':{
                'tokenizer': 'keyword',
                'filter': 'lowercase'
             }
          }
       }
    }
  },
  'mappings': {
    'example':{
        'properties': {
          'group'            : {'type' : 'string', 'analyzer': 'analyzer_keyword'},
          'description'       : {'type' : 'string', 'analyzer': 'analyzer_keyword'},
          'names'          : {'type' : 'string', 'analyzer': 'analyzer_keyword'}
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I need to use bool (must, must_not, should) queries combined to regular expressions due to my context (I need to search partial patterns). It works well for all of my fields except the ones containing a dot character.

For example, 
`names` is a string array which contains data with dots:
`"cyap7_1.pe3269","synp6_1.pe2492","syns3_1.pe382","cyap8_1.pe2829"`

Here is some examples of what works (return results as expected) and what does not work (returns no results):

Simple query works:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/example/test/_search?q=cyap7_1.pe3269"
```

Simple query with partial match does not work:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/example/test/_search?q=*cyap7_1.pe3269*"
```

The exact query I want does not work: ***

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/example/test/_search" -d 
  '{ 'query': { 'filtered': { 'filter': 
  {"bool":{"must":{"regexp":{"names":".*cyap7_1.pe3269.*"}}}} } } }'
```

Subpart of this query works:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/example/test/_search" -d 
  '{ 'query': { 'filtered': { 'filter': 
  {"bool":{"must":{"regexp":{"names":".*pe3269.*"}}}} } } }'


curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/example/test/_search" -d 
  '{ 'query': { 'filtered': { 'filter': 
  {"bool":{"must":{"regexp":{"names":".*cyap7_1.*"}}}} } } }'
```

Subpart of this query with dot does not work (even with regexp improvements):

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/example/test/_search" -d 
  '{ 'query': { 'filtered': { 'filter': 
  {"bool":{"must":{"regexp":{"names":".*1.pe3.*"}}}} } } }'


curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/example/test/_search" -d 
  '{ 'query': { 'filtered': { 'filter': 
  {"bool":{"must":{"regexp":{"names":".*cyap7_1\.pe3269.*"}}}} } } }'


curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/example/test/_search" -d 
  '{ 'query': { 'filtered': { 'filter': 
  {"bool":{"must":{"regexp":{"names":".*cyap7_1\\.pe3269.*"}}}} } } }'


curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/example/test/_search" -d 
  '{ 'query': { 'filtered': { 'filter': 
  {"bool":{"must":{"regexp":{"names":".*cyap7_1.*pe3269.*"}}}} } } }'
```

*** How can I make this query working ?

**UPDATE**

This is really weird but now it works for:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/example/test/_search" -d 
  '{ 'query': { 'filtered': { 'filter': 
  {"bool":{"must":{"regexp":{"names":".*cyap7_1.pe3269.*"}}}} } } }'
```

What happens is that I already had my indexes created when I updated them to add the field `names`.
So, after the update `.*cyap7_1.*` and `.*pe3269.*` worked but not `.*cyap7_1.pe3269.*` which was really strange and which was why I created the post.

But now, I deleted the index and then recreated it. And it works for `.*cyap7_1.pe3269.*`...
The update kind of fails the indexation of the entire term...

Comment: Did you try putting the dot into a character class like `.*cyap7_1[.]pe3269.*`?

Comment: What do you mean "does not work"? It doesn't return the document, or it does return it?

Comment: Isn't dot a special character in regexp?

Comment: - @stribizhev Does not work either.
 - @AndreiStefan I precised that `does not work` means `returns no results`.
 - @MBudnik Yes it is, but a dot can be a dot and even an escaped dot returns no results.

Comment: It works after deleting and recreating my indexes ><' See my update...